# How to select an entity from database based on nested list item match?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have a DbSet that contains a list of `Item`, Now I want to search an `Item` from the database based on its nested list item matching.

## Item Model

```
public int ItemID{ get; set; }
public string Cover { get; set; }
public List<SlideModel> Slides { get; set; }
```

## Slide Model

```
public int SlideID{ get; set; }
public int ItemID{ get; set; }
public string Slide{ get; set; }
```

Now I will pass a search string of `Slide` and it will search for the `Item` who have the `Slide` in its `List<SlideModel>` and return the `Item`

```
item = await context.Items
    .Include(i => i.Slides)
    .Where(...todo-maybe...)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

How should I write the Query method to get the `item` based on the `slide`

Comment: *based on its nested list item matching* -- Please elaborate. An example of what you want would help.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, Please see the edited question, I just want to select an item that contain the slide in its `SlideList`.

Comment: And where are you stuck trying this?

Comment: The query method, How should i write it to get the result?

Comment: Which criteria in where method, my friend?

Comment: am I not clear enough with my question, I'm new to EF Core. Please see the last portion of my code that's all i want to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the thing that you want? Hope to help, my friend :))

```
string inputSlide = "abc";

item = await context.Items
    .Include(i => i.Slides)
    .Where(i => i.Slides.Any(i => i.Slide.ToLower() == inputSlide.ToLower()))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: really helped, Thank you.

Comment: @SabirHossain: Well played, my friend :))